# developer payload

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am not sure on how to set the developer payload field when the user wants to proceed with an in app purchase. The situation is the following:

1. non consumable item (ex: to unlock premium features)
2. no server backend available (i can only do local checks)
3. no user login/password available

Regarding the 3rd point, i preferer to not ask the user to enter its email or any other type of informations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a random string, any random string will do. one option for example is to use the device id:

```
String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                                            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID))
```

Than you provide it to iab API as the last parameter of getBuyIntent on IInAppBillingService:

```
public android.os.Bundle getBuyIntent(int apiVersion, java.lang.String packageName, java.lang.String sku, java.lang.String type, java.lang.String developerPayload) throws android.os.RemoteException;
```

and you read it back in onActivityResult():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ...
    String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
```

purchaseData is the data returned from in-app-billing API, structured as a json:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
String developerPayload = o.optString("developerPayload");
```

you need to verify that the developerPayload returned in onActivityResult is the one you supplied in getBuyIntent. if you are using an arbitrary String, you can store it in the application shared preferences in between the calls.

Comment: Mmm, but if the user uninstall the app and install it again or the same user has another phone on which he want to run the app, a random string or the device id won't work. Note that i am talking about non consumable items.

Comment: if you use the deviceId as I showed above than un-installing and re-installing on the same device is taken care of, as the deviceId stays the same. If you wish to allow the user to install the app on a different device than you must take user information into account and store it on a server - which you said you don't want to.

Comment: @MarcoMasci : A _developerPayload_ you generate is valid for that transaction only. You can generate a different string as _developerPayload_ for the second purchase. If same user(gmail Id) has another phone, you can get all the items purchased from that gmailId using _getSkuDetails()_. Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html)

Comment: Using Secure.ANDROID_ID is inappropriate in the case when user gets a new device. The original question is valid and not yet responded. I did not find better solution than using constant in this case. Using constant is useless however from the security point of view.